# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process when bulding project using maven

Tags: java, maven, build, war

Have a problem with bulding multiple project using maven.
Java 1.8.361 (but trying 1.8.202 too)
Getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.2.2:war (default-war) on project projectname-backoffice: Error assembling WAR: Problem creating war: Execution exception (and the archive is probably corrupt but I could not delete it): java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\projectname-dev\qwe-qwe\projectname\projectname-backoffice\target\projectname-backoffice\WEB-INF\lib\gmbal-api-only-3.1.0-b001.jar (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process) -> [Help 1]
```

But if i trying to build this project on other PC, its bulding ok.
I tried reinstall Intellij Idea, reinstall JDK, restart PC, kill all java processes before bulding, but all of this doesn't work.
Also this happens on another .jar files, for example when in my projects building EAR/JAR/WAR files, this error will be present with other .jar libraries from project directory for example on jackson-databind 2.0.5

But if i trying to build this project on other PC, its bulding ok.
I tried reinstall Intellij Idea, reinstall JDK, restart PC, kill all java processes before bulding, but all of this doesn't work.

Comment: Use a tool (depends on OS version) to determine what is locking the file.  But I would guess that jar file that was just built is being scanned.  Make sure the virus protection software is up to date and correctly configured.

Comment: @AndrewS I tried to scan .jar file by IObit Unlocker, this tool present that my .jar file from target directory using only by one java.exe process which building my project. Virus protection ok, because other projects clean+build ok. I originally assumed that trouble is related to SVN. SVN scanning project, trying to analize diffirense and block files, but i marked target directory as ignored for SVN and its doesn't help me too.

Comment: The strangest thing is that the project was building normally until my Discord broke. I found instructions that said to remove temporary files from %AppData% and %LocalAppData% associated with discord. After removing them and reinstalling Disroad, this problem appeared (but I'm not sure about it)

Answer (score 0):

### Windows

Since jar-files can contain a computer-virus your Antivirus-Software might check the `gmbal-api-only-3.1.0-b001.jar` for virus at build-time. In order to scan for virus an exclusive write (and maybe exclusive read) lock is performed.

Try to exclude the directory `C:\projectname-dev` from search for virus in your antivirus software. **Warning:** This might violate your company security constraints. Contact your Administrator.

Antivirus (and Endpoint-Protection) might hide his own lock-and-scan-process from being spoted by IObit Unlocker and similar software.

Comment: But other projects bulding normally, also buld crashed on different .jar libraries, for example on jackson-databind. To exclude a variant of the problem in the project itself i tried to build this on other PC and it built ok.

Comment: Thats correct. The antivirus check all jars. Jackson-Databind is huge ('bout 1.5 MB), it takes some time to check that. How big is `gmbal-api-only-3.1.0-b001jar`? Is it huge too?